# Compare two nested objects and return an object with the keys which are into both of object

Tags: object, nested

Let say that I have these two nested objects:

```
const sourceKeys = {
  school: {
    name: "Elisa Lemonnier",
    students: 250
  },
  house: {
    room : 2,
    kids: true,
    assets: "elevator",
  }
}
const targetKeys = {
  school: {
    name: "Lucie Faure",
    students: 150,
    address: "123 Main St.",
    phone: "555-555-5555"
  },
   house: {
    room : 4,
    kids: false,
    assets: "Garden",
    shop: "Auchan"
  }
}
```

And I want the `targetKeys` keep ONLY the keys that are in `sourceKeys`. So I will get that :

```
const targetKeysMatchingSourceKeys = {
  school: {
    name: "Lucie Faure",
    students: 150,
  },
   house: {
    room : 4,
    kids: false,
    assets: "Garden",
  }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed given that is a nested object. So, I will appreciate any help.
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution, here is

```
const filteredJSON = Object.assign({}, TargetJsonToObject)

// Recursive function to filter the properties of the object
function filterObject(SourceJsonToObject, filteredObj) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(filteredObj)) {
    // If the key is not present in the source JSON, delete it from filtered JSON
    if (!SourceJsonToObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      delete filteredObj[key]
    } else if (typeof filteredObj[key] === "object") {
      // If the key is present in the source JSON and the value is an object, recursively call the function on the nested object
      filterObject(SourceJsonToObject[key], filteredObj[key])
    }
  }
}

filterObject(SourceJsonToObject, TargetJsonToObject)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).